# i cant point on a login button on a website like this

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

hi there i ve been trying to make script to login similiar to instagram.com

but the script doesnt work

here is the code
public class Testinggg {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Download\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/");
Thread.sleep(3000);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("login-ddl-link"));
driver.findElement(By.id("login-ddl-link")).click();
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe-accounts");
WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.className("fcn8k"));
driver.findElement(By.className("fcn8k")).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the code, there is no problem with the code. But when I open the instagram homepage link. I could not find the button id "accounts-menu".

Please check the button id and execute it once again.

```
// code to Search for the element
WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.className("fcn8k"));
// code to click the required button
loginButton.click(‌​);
```

Comment: yes i try to find the id for login button can you help me with the code?

Comment: what exactly you need ?

Comment: i just need to click the login button on the bottom right but the button doesnt seems to have an id can you help me thank you very much

Comment: you can use the className. "_fcn8k"

Comment: driver.find_element_by_class_name("fcn8k").click()
is this the right code?

Comment: WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.className("fcn8k"));loginButton.click();

Comment: it doesnt work too. could you help me by take a look at the code on top i have edited it.

Comment: help please     test